# Find Maximum in Array with Repeated Elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I faced a question in an interview two days back regarding optimally finding the maximum element in an array and I have query regarding that.

The array as described by interviewer consists of integer values which may **repeat** (not necessarily in consecutive places) and it also consists of two parts (One part may be empty) : First part in *non-decreasing* order, and second part in *non-increasing* order,i.e. if a[n] is an array consisting of n integer values, then, a[i]<=a[i+1],i in [1,m] and a[j]>=a[j+1],j in [m,n] and m lies somewhere between 1 and n inclusive. Now, they asked me to find the **maximum value in the array** in most efficient way.

I argued that as some elements may be repeated, I cannot element a search space using divide and conquer strategy. Had all the elements been distinct, we would be able to find maximum in *lg n* time using *binary search*. But there exists at least one input sequence (possibly when all elements are same) for which we at least need to have n-1 comparison before we can tell which element is maximum.

The interviewer asked me to think if I can impose some restriction on the input so that the problem can be solved in *lg n* time. I was not able to solve at that time and still thinking.

It would be helpful if you can help me in thinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interviewer was trying to see if you know about [ternary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search): if you require that the parts are strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing, you'd be able to get an answer in `Log3(N)`. So the additional requirement the interviewer was looking for is probably that duplicate entries, if any, should occur on different sides of the ascending-descending switchover point.

Comment: Except ternary search requires the function to be partly _strictly_ increasing and partly _strictly_ decreasing.

Comment: @Shahbaz I meant to answer the "interviewer asked me to think if I can impose some restriction on the input so that the problem can be solved in lg n time" part of the question. The first part of the OP's answer is correct.

Comment: But Unimodal function unimodal function is a function that is either **strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing** or vice versa. And moreover, I guess, that can be done using binary search also. Using binary search I can get it in Log2(n). But if elements are repeated, then??? (Say , all elements are same)

Comment: @sarthak I'm sorry that the initial answer was not clear: you answered the first part of the question correctly, it's the second part (find an addition condition to impose on the array to make it possible to search in `Log(N)`) that can be addressed with ternary search. Binary search would not work, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "So the additional requirement the interviewer was looking for is probably that duplicate entries, if any, should occur on different sides of the ascending-descending switchover point." - This clarifies the idea. But the interviewer at some point of time asked me to think if there are 1000 elements in the array and all are "2".

Comment: @sarthak An array of 1000 2s is a counterexample that shows that if you allow repeated items on either side of the switchover point you are limited to a linear search. However, if you have something like `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 0}`, both 2 and 4 are repeated, but you can still find the max in Log3(N).

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight. I got the idea now.